# A probability problem involving discrete space

Tags: probability

[image]

Call $X$ the number of black balls in Box A after swapping. We want $E(X)$. We have 3 situations. First, if the exchange is Black-Black or White-White, then the situation is unchanged and we have

$$ P(X=1) = 1/3 $$

and $P(X=2 )= 2/3$

Now, if we exchange a black for a white ball, we have

$$ P(X=1) = 1/3 $$

and if we exchange white for black now we have 3 black balls in box A and so

$$ P(X=1) = 1/3, P(X=2) = 2/3, P(X=3 ) = 1 $$

This is how I approached this problem, but I am still unsure on whether this is correct. In general, I find this type of problems a lot challenging than continuous rv's. What strategy can we use to handle this type of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_A$ denote the event that a black marble is selected from box A.

Let $W_A$ denote the event that a white marble is selected from box A.

Likewise define $B_B$ and $W_B$ wrt box B.

Then:

- $P(B_A\cap B_B)=P(B_A)P(B_B\mid B_A)=\frac23\frac23=\frac49$
- $P(W_A\cap W_B)=P(W_A)P(W_B\mid W_A)=\frac13\frac23=\frac29$
- $P(B_A\cap W_B)=P(B_A)P(W_B\mid B_A)=\frac23\frac13=\frac29$
- $P(W_A\cap B_B)=P(W_A)P(B_B\mid W_A)=\frac13\frac13=\frac19$

If $X$ denotes the number of black balls in box A after swapping then:

- $\{X=2\}=(B_A\cap B_B)\cup(W_A\cap W_B)$
- $\{X=1\}=B_A\cap W_B$
- $\{X=3\}=W_A\cap B_B$

So that: $$\mathbb EX=P(B_A\cap W_B)+2[P(B_A\cap B_B)+P(W_A\cap W_B)]+3P(W_A\cap B_B)=$$$$\frac29+2\left[\frac49+\frac29\right]+3\frac19=\frac{17}9$$